# Repeat a Sequence Action in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have an actor called arrow that I want to repeat a sequence action to it.

This arrow points to an actor which if is clicked the arrow should fade out.

Here is my code:

```
Action moving = Actions.sequence(
                (Actions.moveTo(arrow.getX(), arrow.getY() - 35, 1)),
                (Actions.moveTo(arrow.getX(), arrow.getY(), 1)));
arrow.addAction(moving);
actor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                arrow.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));
            }
        });
```

Code works fine but I want to repeat 'moving' action untile actor is clicked.

I read about RepeatAction in this question [Cannot loop an action. libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645664/cannot-loop-an-action-libgdx) but I didn't know how I can apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RepeatAction in this case, with `Actions.forever()`:

```
final Action moving = Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
        (Actions.moveTo(arrow.getX(), arrow.getY() - 35, 1)),
        (Actions.moveTo(arrow.getX(), arrow.getY(), 1))));
arrow.addAction(moving);
actor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        // you can remove moving action here
        arrow.removeAction(moving);
        arrow.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1f));
    }
});
```

If you want to remove `arrow` from `Stage` after fading out, you can use `RunnableAction`:

```
arrow.addAction(Actions.sequence(
        Actions.fadeOut(1f), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arrow.remove();
            }
        }))
);
```